# Sharing data across executors in Apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-2.3

My SPARK project (written in Java) requires to access (SELECT query results) different tables across executors.

**One solution to this problem is :**

1. I create a tempView
2. select required columns
3. using **forEach** convert `DataFrame` to `Map`.
4. pass that map as a **broadcast variable** across executors.

However, I have found that

1. there many complex queries whose result cant be stored directly in `Map`
2. Tables are very large and hence creating `Map` of large size and passing it to executors as a broadcast variable doesn't sound efficient.

**Instead can we load tables in-memory using `load` which can be shared across executors?**

Is **`void org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.createOrReplaceTempView(String viewName)`**

or **`void org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.createGlobalTempView(String viewName) throws AnalysisException`**

Method useful for this purpose?

**SPARK VERSION : 2.3.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast a DataFrame. See [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#broadcast-hint-for-sql-queries)